# I'm stuck in a basic Mongodb php tutorial

Tags: php, mongodb

I was following this tutorial : http://pronewb.com/mongodb-as-in-humongous-not-retarded. All was well until the "I feel the vibe" section. I do not know where to begin this section. Do i have to create a new php file or type it in some command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in that section, and following ones, is PHP code so yes it should be in a PHP file.

Note that the pieces of code presented are demonstrations of the syntax and usage, rather than snippets that you can expect to copy/paste and execute on their own.

Comment: thanks salathe. I'm really a beginner in this. Are you aware of any tutorials that more complete?

Comment: A very good, basic starting point would be from the MongoDB section of the PHP manual: http://php.net/mongo.tutorial -- If you have any troubles, thoughts, additions or improvements for that tutorial page then do let me know ( [email](http://goo.gl/56HF) ); we like the documentation to be as helpful as possible.